# How to bind CTRL + scroll to a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to bind CTRL + scroll inside a `matplotlib` figure to a zoom function. I know that in `matplotlib` I can use `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', buttonpressed)` to bind a certain button to a function (`buttonpressed`) and use `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', scrollused)` to bind scrolling to a function (`scrollused`), but what is the best way to combine this two?

Is there a possibility to bind both combined to a single function call? Or do I have to resort to working around it? For example, setting a variable to true whenever CTRL is pressed and to false whenever it is released again, and checking for this variable in the scroll function call?

The binds can be found [here.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html)

Minimal working example of a figure with CTRL bind and scroll bind (but not combined):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def scrolled(event):
    print('scroll used')

def ctrlpressed(event):
    if event.key == 'control':
        print('CTRL pressed')

# Bind to figure
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', ctrlpressed)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', scrolled)
fig.show()
```

Comment: `fig.show()` need an **body** before testing. Which gui are you using ? TK ? How to bind an function without **mainloop** ?

Comment: I am able to just run this MWE, with or without `fig.show()`. Making a call to the `mpl_connect` method will automatically turn interactive Tk mode on. Script output: `>>>Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.`

Comment: So you told to us : "i got bind_key function without body ?". Generate output and play with this. Otherwise you can't bind function like this.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but the MWE works just fine. It will output a figure and will react to the ctrl and scroll binds. These binds have nothing to do with Tk or a GUI, they come with `matplotlib`. My question is if there is a good way to combine the ctrl and the scroll bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found until now is to bind the ctrl press, the ctrl release, and the scroll separate. The control press sets a check variable to true, the ctrl release sets it to false again. The scroll checks for this variable. In this case the result feels like a ctrl+scroll for the user.

See code for the example given in the post (the globals are a workaround for this MWE. In my own code I am using an object oriented approach):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

ctrl = False

def scrolled(event):
    global ctrl
    if ctrl:
        print('ctrl+scroll used')

def ctrlpressed(event):
    global ctrl
    if event.key == 'control':
        ctrl = True

def ctrlreleased(event):
    global ctrl
    if event.key == 'control':
        ctrl = False
        

# Bind to figure
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', ctrlpressed)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', ctrlreleased)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', scrolled)
fig.show()
```